# GCP AI platform Custom prediction routine fails to load model with pipeline, with error: 92

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, joblib, gcp-ai-platform-training

I'm currently trying to deploy a model to GCP AI platform using https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/custom-prediction-routine-scikit-learn as guidance. When running `gcloud beta ai platform versions create` I get the following error which turns up no hits as of 20 feb 2020:

```
Creating version (this might take a few minutes)......failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ai-platform.versions.create) Create Version failed. Bad model detected with 
error:  "Failed to load model: Unexpected error when loading the model: 92 (Error code: 0)"
```

My model is a Sci-kit learn multinominal Naive Bayes Classifier that uses two tf/idf vectorizers (word and char level) in a pipeline. I store the entire pipeline with joblib version 0.13.0, which matches the one supported on GCP (link: https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/runtime-version-list).

Following the tutorial I've tar.gz'ed the code supposed to serve this and stored the model and pickled preprocessor in a bucket. Following advice elsewhere I've also stored the preprocessor with joblib, which sadly also doesnt work.

I've `joblib.load`'ed the model just fine and served a prediction in 0.13.0, so I'm about to pull my hairs out.

UPDATE: I've checked and redid pickling/joblibbing several times, even going as far as setting up a new virtualenv to match 1.15 and redoing training from scratch.

I've resorted to exposing my models behind a flask application and deploying it to app engine, this runs fine but is probably a little bit overkill for just two models. Works fine.

Comment: Did you take a look at this?: https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/troubleshooting

Comment: Yeah, but those docs refer to training on GAIP (= submitting them as jobs) - I'm offloading the training to a VM because of the added flexibility in development. I'm getting this issue when I try to deploy models with the custom prediction; which I use as  I'd need to return probabilities and need some more pre-processing of my data. The error seems to indicate some kind of joblib/pickle issue but I've checked it and even completely redid my training in a virtual environment that matches 1.15. I think the model architecture (being a pipeline) is the problem.

Comment: Did you try running the command gcloud ai-platform versions create instead of  gcloud beta ai platform versions create?